# Date format for asp.net mvc website in Windows 2008

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, datetime-format

I installed an asp.net mvc website from windows 2003 to windows 2008. From start the date format is displayed as m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt when on 2003 it is displayed as yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
[image]
If I try to run this site through visual studio on 2003 or 2008 or windows 7 or xp, the pages pull correct format but if I run this through IIS, it shows wrong format (m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt ).

I have edited the HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International to have desired date format but no luck!
[image]

I tried changing region and language too... no luck.

[image]
Any ideas anyone?!

Here is the first call to get the date time...
[image]

Thanks in advance.

No luck with suggestion:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code for printing the date?

Comment: Code is provided at the end of question. This code is running on windows 7 machine and not on server so it works as expected. But on server it shows wrong date format.

Answer (score 0):

To control the output date format(Culture) I would you suggest to control it at application level in the web.config

This can be easily done trough the globalization element:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It is possible you want to set both as culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US". Additionally this will provide some sample code to test http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162

Comment: You have to select the correct culture, those are just sample cultures. Based on the format you want. It is possible you want to set both as culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US". Additionally this will provide some sample to test support.microsoft.com/kb/306162 –

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any effect of changing culture on the resultant date time format. I tried fr-CA and en-Us and others. But the dates don't change.

Comment: I have done this in the past, I have seen it working in this way. Did you try the sameple code on the link?